# Creating a Wrapper .exe for launching Kite with Intel SDE for use in Sublime Text

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3, exe, wrapper

I have an old CPU (Intel Pentium G3450 @ 3.4Ghz) and 6GB of DDR3 RAM.

I wanted to run Kite Autocomplete In Sublime Text but the installer said my PC Needs to support AVX.

Then I Found Out about **"Intel SDE"**, It is an emulation layer which can run AVX apps on non AVX CPU !

**So I Managed to Install Kite using Intel SDE with this command :-** *(NOTE : I have added SDE to path for easy usage)*

`sde -- "C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\KiteSetup.exe"`

Although I got an error saying "Kite installation Timeout : Try Turning off Antivirus. Splash screen will close now", But I think It Installed Already.
It is showing up in Control Panel and I can Also see 1GB of Files in Kite Folder in Program Files.

So Now comes the problem, How do I make Sublime Text Launch Kite using Intel SDE ? Maybe some C++ Wrapper ?

**HERE ARE THE THINGS I TRIED :-**

1. I tried editing the kite sublime package file but couldn't decode the format.
2. I renamed original `kited.exe` to `kited1.exe`. Then I created a batch file with launch command and then packaged it to an exe with Bat-to-Exe tool and saved as `kited.exe` in Kite Folder. It Did launched kite successfully but kite doesn't seem to be Connected to Sublime Text (Note : I have already installed the plugin from package Control). It just Launches and then Terminates after some time.

Edit : -
Content of batch file is `sde -- "C:\Program Files\Kite\kited1.exe"`

Comment: Is the content of the batch file you pointlessly hid inside an extractable exectuable wrapper a huge secret? I don't understand how you can expect programming advice for a specific issue based upon the current content of your question. Please make sure that you've read through your question, as if you're one of us, and then all of the linked content of [ask]. After you've done that, please use the [edit] facility to make the required improvements, if you wish to receive assistance with an on topic and answerable question.

Comment: The `Kite.sublime-package` file is in plain ZIP format. To edit it, you can either unzip it to a temp folder, make your changes, zip it back up, and replace the original, or you can use the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin, which extracts it to the `Packages` folder for you.

Comment: @Compo there is nothing secret. Batch file just said ```sde -- "C:\Program Files\Kite\kited1.exe"```

Comment: Highly recommend not using `PackageResourceViewer` to extract the package for you unless the `Kite` package is no longer under active development, because extracting it that way will lock you into the currently installed version forever unless you manually remove the files.